# Connecting two sentences with comma and without a connector

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, commas, connotations

In the below sentence, why there was comma without a connector or transition?  What rule allows separation of two sentences with comma and without connector?

Is this phrase (the fulfillment of prophecy that) enough to connect the two sentences

> He believed Mike to be death, **the fulfillment of prophecy that** said one day Mike would be death at young age.

Comment: This sentence is incorrect in several ways. Where did you see it?

Comment: I saw similar in a book I read.

Comment: Please quote the exact sentence that you saw.

Comment: What book?? Please don't be coy.  Tell us simply and clearly which book.  Provide a link, if possible.

Comment: I have paraphrase the above sentence so I doubted the benefit of sharing the script from the book. The original sentence "The way the Spanish interpreted Montezuma’s remarks, the Aztec king was making an astonishing concession: he believed Cortés to be a god, the fulfillment of an ancient prophecy that said an exiled deity would one day return from the east," says Malcolm Gladwell in his book "talking to stranger".

Comment: Your paraphrase has entirely broken the grammar.  I've voted to close this question, because it isn't clear if we should try make an answer relevant to the text in the question or in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use commas to separate out extra information to make the sentence easier to read.

For example, you could say:

> I visited Edinburgh, the capital city of Scotland.

The additional information about Edinburgh appears after a comma.

You can also use commas for parenthesis, and then continue the sentence. For example:

> I went to Edinburgh, the capital city of Scotland, with my family.

In your example, "he" believes Mike "to be death". He also believes that Mike is "the fullfillment of prophecy". The comma just separates these two items.