# Connecting two sentences with only a comma - no connector

Tags: commas

In the sentence below, why is there a comma without a connector or transition?  What rule allows separation of two sentences with a comma but without a connector?

Is this phrase ("the fulfilment of prophecy that") enough to connect the two sentence fragments?

- He believed Mike to be death, the fulfilment of prophecy that said one day Mike would be death at young age.

Comment: You posted an identical question on ELL, which is getting different comments and answers from this post. Perhaps you can cross-reference the two; otherwise, information will be scattered throughout SE and people who want to see replies to this question may not find all of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting two sentences with comma and without a connector](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305844/connecting-two-sentences-with-comma-and-without-a-connector)